# SQL statement using count and avg

Tags: sql, database

My question -> what's the average of children a woman can have. Give the number of children in the column.

```
Relations:

human (name, gender, age) 
parent (ParentName, ChildName) -> is subset of human(name)
```

What I got so far:

```
SELECT AMOUNT
FROM human h
JOIN parent p ON h.name = p.parentname
WHERE gender = 'f' AND h.name IN (p.parentname) AND AVG(COUNT(childname))
```

Desired outcome:

```
AMOUNT : 1.33333333333333333333333333333333333333E00
```

Comment: ohh right,  so AVG(COUNT(childname))) ?

Comment: What does this mean:  "What's the women average of children"?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry I edited it. Is it more clear now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) / count(distinct h.name)
FROM human h JOIN
     parent p
     ON h.name = p.parentname
WHERE h.gender = 'f';
```

This calculates the average for women who have children.  For all women:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) * 1.0 / count(distinct h.name)
FROM human h LEFT JOIN
     parent p
     ON h.name = p.parentname
WHERE h.gender = 'f';
```

Comment: Yes something like this but it seems that p.amount is an invalid identifier.

Comment: @Lyaso . . . `p` is clearly defined as a table alias for `parent`.

Comment: but what about amount ? Amount is not defined. For what stands amount ?

Comment: I know that the average is 8 / 6 which is the correct solution. There are 8 children from 6 women. So the average is 1.33*

Comment: @Lyaso . . . I saw that in your question and thought it was something like "amount of children".

Answer (score 0):

you can use `subquery` to get female children based on `case` statement. then compute the `average`.

I used `left join` in case there are missed records of children.

```
select avg(fCount), sum(totalChildren)
from (select case when gender='f' then count(1) else 0 end as fCount
    , sum(1) as totalChildren
    from human h
    left join parent p on p.parentname = hm.name
    group by gender) t1
```

Comment: I'd be willing to bet that this poster's classwork has not reached the topic of subqueries and CASE yet.

Comment: hmm what about the overall amount of children ?

Comment: @Lyaso, use sum() for total children

Comment: Pretty sure the query won't run.

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ I get this error message -> The following columns are missing in the result of your query:
sumofchildren
The following columns are too much in the result of your query:
AVG(FCOUNT)
SUM(TOTALCHILDREN)

Comment: I tried this in sqlserver, can you post your entire query?

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ Ok sorry the desired outcome should only be the average of children women can have.